Most appropriate way to defining enums as strings to make json data more human readable in C#
I am looking for most appropriate way to define string enums (??) in C#, so that I can make JSON format more human readable:  instead of passing integer values for enums, pass an actual string.
For reference, I have done this in python: it is rather simple, however not so in C# it seems:
in python i can do this:
define my enums:
from enum import Enum 
class AgeUnits(str, Enum):
    DAYS = "Days"
    WEEKS = "Weeks"
    MONTHS = "Months"
    YEARS = "Years"

Define my model, including dfefault values:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Fields
class AgeInfo(BaseModel):
    age: int  = Field(5)
    age_units: AgeUnits = Field(AgeUnits.YEARS, alias="ageUnits")

I can then accept a human readable value for Age Units "Weeks" in Json and get a AgeUnits.WEEKS in the model, once deserialized:
{
    "age": 10,
    "ageUnits": "Weeks"
}

This seems a lot friendlier to deal with "AgeUnits":2 in Json.
How do i do something like that in C#?

you can add [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] attribute

Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0#enums-as-strings

Newtonsoft: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm

thank  you..  what about if string value in the Enum needed to contain space? like in my python example of enum i can have a value of WEEKS_METRIC = "Metric Weeks"
